# Mount point inside encrypted partition doesn't mount

Tags: 10.04, encryption, fstab

This seems a very simple problem but it's driving me nuts. I'm trying to mount two ext4 partitions at boot time with /etc/fstab.(They are written differently because I read in a forum that there were some problems mounting by uuid)

Here are the two lines:

```
UUID=c7fa17c3-e1e0-489e-93ec-341928069664 /home/alice/VirtualGarden ext4 rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async 0 2

/dev/sda8 /home/alice/Saco  ext4 rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async 0 3
```

The main problem is that after boot I won't have access to either partition. They appear in my desktop, but when I try to list their content they are empty. Everything works if I mount them as a normal user after boot. For example:

```
mount /home/alice/Saco
```

I don't know if this makes a difference, but the mount point (/home/alice/) is an **encrypted partition**. I tried to move the mount point to /Saco and it mounted perfectly after reboot.

Another thing is that if I use the UUID in fstab Nautilus creates two links for the same partition. I did some research and I have solved this by using  /dev/disk/by-uuid/.

Any tips or advise are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encrypted partition doesn't get mounted unless you provide the password, while the system tries to mount the other partitions before that happens.

The obvious advise: mount your partitions somewhere else (eg., /media/alice/... or /mnt/alice/...). You can place a symlink to those mount points, if you absolutely want them to be accessible from /home/alice/...:

```
ln -s /media/alice/VirtualGarden /home/alice/VirtualGarden
ln -s /media/alice/Saco /home/alice/Saco
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the manual way if you are unclear,install ntfs-config to automount partitions.I have been using this in 10.04 for few months.It is good,just try it.

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

Also see this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11908/is-it-safe-to-shutdown-computer-without-unmounting-ntfs-partitions/11912#11912)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I might try it later, but I'm trying to learn how to do as much as possible through the command line...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your encrypted partition is mounted after the system has tried to mount /home/alice/Saco. As there is no /home/alice at the time system try to mount /home/alice/Saco, then this partition is not mounted but is available to be mounted manually after the system has been booted up. Would you provide information about when you mount your /home/alice encrypted.